# sub domain brute forcer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I attempted to create a sub domain brute forcer in python, but my code doesn't work, there's probably a better way to do it, I just need to be guided in the right direction on how to go about doing this.

```
import sys
import socket
import requests

host = "paypal.com"

sublist = ["cpanel.", "admin.", "manager.", "secure."]

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    status = s.connect_ex((host, 80))
    if status == 0:
       print (host + " is up!")
    else:
       print (host + " is down!")
    s.close()
except socket.error:
     print (host + " is not reachable")

def checklist():
    try:
        for lines in sublist:
            check = requests.get("http://" + lines + host).status_code
            if check == 200:
               print "Found: " + lines + host
    except Exception:
        print "Error"

checklist()
```

it just prints out "Error" in the terminal, I don't know if its checking the sub domains with the host.

How can I loop through the list and check every subdomain with the site to see if its available and then display it on the terminal?

The error without the except code:

raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cpanel.paypal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

Comment: how about printing out the exception instead and fix what causes the error? Its stacktrace and name should help you with that.

Comment: Your indenting looks broken.

Comment: its probably because i tried to copy and paste the code and then I tried to fix all the ident.

Comment: can you add `except Exception as e: print e`

Comment: The question is tagged `python-3.x`, but `print "Found: " + lines + host` is a Python 2.x statement. If you're on Python 3.x this will break. Try using `print(...)` instead of `print ...`

Comment: @timmy I get this error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cpanel.paypal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdffa119350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

Comment: @JustinasMarozas I guess I forgot to add () to print, but the code is still broken, I updated my post with the actual error.

Comment: It's not very nice to test code like this on somebody else's domain.

Comment: @RolandSmith I'm doing paypals bug bounty program through hackersone, I'm just trying to code my own tools, I know I can use something like sublist3r and etc..

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your sending requests too fast,also you can try using headers to cover your python request

```
import time
try:
    time.sleep(1.5)
    check = requests.get("http://" + lines + host).status_code
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    r.status_code = "Connection Refused by Host"
```

Comment: I get Connection Refused by Host. What I also tried was changing the first value on my list from cpanel to cms, and the code kinda works, I get "Found: cms.paypal.com" but then it hangs, I don't know if its going through the list or not.

Comment: it hangs when trying the second value on the list for some reason.

Comment: if the host is up and you get connection refused .most probably your access is denied or your IP is blocked  ,if not remove `.status_code`